# Complex Join Query rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

```
SELECT course_categories.course_category_title, COUNT(*) as count
FROM course_enrollments
JOIN courses ON course_enrollments.course_id = courses.course_id
JOIN course_categories ON course_categories.id = courses.course_category_id"
GROUP BY course_categores.id
ORDER BY courses_categories.title
```

How would I do this in rails: (I tried the below with major errors)

```
category_rs = CourseEnrollment.select("course_categories.title, COUNT(*) as count").
            joins(:courses, :course_categories).
            group("course_categories.id").
            order("course_categories.title")
```

Comment: what errors are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed to specify the join as a string.